# REST API - Retrieving posts with custom status

Tags: posts, rest-api, post-status

I am still in the process of learning how to use the WordPress REST API and am attempting to retrieve all posts which have been assigned the custom status "archived".

I have already created the custom status using the code below:

```
add_action( 'init', 'post_archived_status' );
function post_archived_status() {
    register_post_status( 'archived', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Archived', 'post' ),
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Archived (%s)', 'Archived (%s)'),
        'public'                    => false,
        'exclude_from_search'       => true,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'publicly_queryable'        => true,
    ));
}
```

With the status now created, I tried to use this endpoint to retrieve the filtered posts but received an error message instead.

`https://www.website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?status=archived`

```
{
"code": "rest_invalid_param",
"message": "Invalid parameter(s): status",
"data": {
"status": 400,
"params": {
"status": "Status is forbidden."
},
"details": {
"status": {
"code": "rest_forbidden_status",
"message": "Status is forbidden.",
"data": {
"status": 401
}
}
}
}
}
```

I have done some research and believe it may be something to do with authorisation however, I wouldn't have thought that would be needed as I have set `publicly_queryable` to `true`?

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer help, or did you find another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) is needed, because the Posts endpoint will check whether the current user has the [`edit_posts` capability](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/roles-and-capabilities/#edit_posts) – [see `WP_REST_Posts_Controller::sanitize_post_statuses()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_posts_controller/sanitize_post_statuses/). Also, a HTTP status of `401` normally indicates that authentication is required.

So try again, but with an authenticated request, i.e. make sure the current user is logged-in and has the `edit_posts` capability.